# Converting to MIPS assembly Language with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, assembly, mips, pipeline

Not the best at converting, especially to MIPS assembly Language.

This was the original Code:

```
void swap(int v[], int k, int j) { 
int temp; 
temp = v[k]; 
v[k] = v[j]; 
v[j] = temp; 
}
```

With some help we managed to get to this, now i need to convert this to MIPS Assembly code, only just finished learning Java still a noob. Any help is welcome.

```
k = k << 2;
k = k + v
j = j << 2;
j = j + v
temp0 = load(k)
temp1 = load(j)
store(k) = temp1
store(j) = temp0
```

Comment: Think about how the compiler implements it: it just lays out a bunch of consecutive memory spaces and saves a pointer to the first one. In order to calculate an address you just calculate an offset from that - e.g. index 0 is an offset of 0 * 32 (0), index 1 is 1* 32, index 2 is 2 * 32, etc. (BTW it's much easier to go from C to MIPS Assembly Language than from Java to MIPS Assembly Language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's the asm. It *is* predicated on the pseudo code above, but I wrote it from scratch, based upon the HLL at the top.

It *is* mips ABI conforming. Thus, it is at liberty to change (i.e. destroy) the argument registers. Thus, if called in a loop, caller must set `a0-a3` before each call.

```
#   void
#   swap(int v[],int k,int j)
#   {
#       int temp;
#
#       temp = v[k];
#       v[k] = v[j];
#       v[j] = temp;
#   }

# swap -- swap two elements in an array
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- pointer to array
#   a1 -- array index "k"
#   a2 -- array index "j"
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- v[k]
#   t1 -- v[j]
swap:
    sll     $a1,$a1,2               # k <<= 2 (i.e. byte offset)
    addu    $a1,$a1,$a0             # get address of v[k]

    sll     $a2,$a2,2               # j <<= 2 (i.e. byte offset)
    addu    $a2,$a2,$a0             # get address of v[j]

    lw      $t0,0($a1)              # fetch v[k]
    lw      $t1,0($a2)              # fetch v[j]

    sw      $t1,0($a1)              # v[k] = v[j]
    sw      $t0,0($a0)              # v[j] = v[k]

    jr      $ra                     # return
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I know `sll` stands for shift left. What does `addu` stand for??

The `u` "suffix" stands for *unsigned*. But, *not* like it's used in a lot of other places.

There are two versions [of `add`]. The *signed* version is `add` and the *unsigned* version `addu`. They *both* produce *exactly* the same results because they both do the same two's complement addition.

The *only* difference is that if an addition causes an overflow, `add` will generate a processor exception (e.g. "arithmetic overflow") but `addu` will *not*--it will just wrap. Similar for `sub` and underflow.

For example, if a register had `0x7FFFFFFF` in it and you add one to it, this causes an overflow. That is because you're starting with the maximum signed *positive* value, you *add* one to it, and *voila* you're at the maximum signed *negative* value (i.e. a "quantum leap" known as overflow).

So, when adding things that might *legitimately* overflow (i.e. "wrap" in 32 bits) like address calculations, it is better to use the unsigned version.

That is because, in mips, some parts of the program [code/data/stack] may be loaded at 0x80000000 or higher.

For example, the stack might start at `0x80001000` and if you push enough data onto it (i.e. the `$sp` register is being decremented with `sub`), it will eventually hit the neighborhood of `0x80000000`. As you push/pop in the vicinity of this address, you'll get overflow/underflow.

This is *not* wrong--it is natural, and you don't want the processor to generate an exception when you do the `sub` for the push operation, so you use `subu` [and/or the *immediate* form of the instruction `subiu`].

If you haven't already found it, here is a pretty good instruction set reference [that a lot of people use]: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html It is an easy read and covers most of the instructions you're likely to need/use.

Here is a brief overview of the ABI calling conventions: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/altReg.html

Comment: Hey @CraigEstey , thanks so much, you learn something new everyday. Just a query i know "sll" stands for shift left. What does "addu" stand for??

Comment: `sll` stands for "shift left logical"